# Not able to use wifi with lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

i can find a way to connect to my wifi. Theres no problem with ethernet connection but the other way is the problem. I try to follow this solution i found [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) but it doesnt work.

Comment: Is your wifi hardware Broadcom-based? Or something else?

Comment: this is what i get when i look up for Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4315] (rev 01) @user535733

Comment: Good. When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean that the installation failed somehow? (how?) Or that upon reboot, the hardware still did not function?

Comment: upon rebooting the hardware didnt function. I got some warnings when attempting to install the drivers @user535733

Comment: It would really help if we knew _exactly_ what those warnings were. Cannot help you much without that key information. All this information needs to be in your original question, not buried among the comments.